# using project-level templates django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am pretty new to django and I am trying to use a project-level template as my project is supposed to contain more than one sigle app. In order to do this I have created a `layout.html` file were all my templates are supposed to extend from. Here is my files structure:

```
├───Project
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───Courses
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───Courses
│   └───__pycache__
└───PyCourse
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───static
    │   └───PyCourse
    ├───templates
    │   └───PyCourse
    └───__pycache__
```

By trying to document my self about how to use project-level templates, I saw that we have to specify to the engine where to look for the templates. That is what I meant to do in my `settings.py` file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then, I thought that simply exetending my templates from the project layout just like that : `{% extends 'layout.html' %}` would work, but I am getting the following error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: layout.html
```

I have seen that some similar questions were asked on the forum, but trying to implement the answers didn't really worked for me. It may be because these were asked many years before.

Anyway, I really thank those who'll be able to help me dealing with that. It have been struggling with it for a while XD

----EDIT1----

The `layout.html` file is in the `templates` folder right there:

```
Project
  └───templates
         └───layout.html
```

Comment: where is `layout.html` located?

Comment: It is located in a folder names ```templates``` in my project folder (where we have the ```setting.py```, ```wsgi.py``` etc... files)

Comment: move it to the `templates` directory inside your `Project` directory. This is what you have specified in `TEMPLATES['DIRS']`.

Comment: Yep that is where it actually is, sorry if I didn't explicited it well

Comment: can you try and `print` the value of `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: Yes of course, I got the location of my Project directory ```C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235193/discussion-between-isen-and-abhyudai).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just been struggling with the same issue and I've managed to solve it so hopefully my solution will work for you. I'm using Django version 3.2.5

### Background

Most other answers to similar issues show a solution where the settings.py file uses

```
...
    DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
]
```

which I think is the old way of producing the paths. Instead, at the start of the settings.py file, you'll see

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

so my recommendation would be to use this convention to produce the template path.

### Solution

The mistake I'd made was assuming that the BASE_DIR was referring to the project sub-folder. It would appear you've done the same thing. So in your example above, I would change this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
etc..
]
```

to this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
...
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'Project/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
etc..
]
```

I think the confusion arises when the `django-admin startproject` command produces the folders (namespaces). Because it puts a sub-folder "Project" inside the project folder "Project" of the same name, it's easy to mistake the BASE_DIR variable for the sub-folder. But it isn't.

```
Project ##This is your BASE_DIR
├───Project ##This is not your BASE_DIR
│   ├───templates ##This is where you're trying to target
│   ├───asgi.py
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───settings.py
│   ├───urls.py
│   ├───wsgi.py
│   └───__pycache__
├───app1
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───app1
│   └───__pycache__
└───manage.py
```

Comment: And of course, just add "Project" to ````[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]```` if you want to use that method. ````[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Project/templates')]````

Comment: Ohh thank you, you've just made me avoiding copying html code again, again, and again. Thank you so much !